# Natural Gas Standby Generator - too far from gas line?

Tags: generator

My renovated house has the electrical panel on the north side and the gas line in the middle of the east side of the house. Distance is about 45 linear feet. Is it possible to install a generator so far from the gas line entry into the house? Any suggestions on how to do this? If possible, then my next step is to reach out to a electrical contractor.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Distance should not matter unless a crazy amount(going around the house a few times).  The flow rate will matter, can the pipe provide enough flow for the generator, and everything else you use gas for at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

A permanently installed generator needs to be located where cables can get to the panel, a gas pipe can get to a gas supply, a safe distance from windows, and a certain distance from property lines and neighbors according to your zoning rules.  45 feet of gas pipe is not a problem.

Satisfying all these needs can sometimes be a problem.   For example, it would seem the north end of the east wall might be a convenient location thinking only about cables and gas pipe.  But maybe that is too close to your neighbor's house.  I don't know of course ... but you need to consider all those things.

Comment: Running the gas line would probably be cheaper than running the electric lines 30 or 40 feet..

Comment: @JACK will you please come tell my plumber?  :)

Comment: Cable or conduit in NJ?... just curious.

Comment: Depends.  An inlet can often be installed using only cable, depending on the routing of it.  A standby usually needs at least some conduit.  I'm pretty sure you know that so maybe I don't understand the question.

Comment: I was thinking about your plumber and wondering how a 3/4' gas line would be more than say: 2-4/0 al, 2/0 al neutral and a #6 cu ground in conduit. (guessed wire size)

Comment: Maybe you're right and it depends on the details.  I installed 15 feet of 10/3 UF for a small tri fuel generator.  $100 for the cable and other parts.    Later got a quote from a plumber to run a gas line to it, $1200.  Obviously if I could do it myself it would be a lot less but I have to tap in to a 50+ year old 1.5" gas pipe, add a tee ...I don't have the knowledge.

Answer (score -1):

You need to get a professional and check the sizing. Your gas feed to your home can only supply so much energy, there is a good possibility it does not have enough. I have a 19 KW alternator and they ran 1 1/2 pipe about 90'. The feed is from a 3/4" black iron pipe. They also adjusted the pressure up a small amount to make it. At the time I had a 125K BTU gas furnace, two hot water tanks plus a gas kitchen in the planning along with a gas dryer. The appliances cost more but over time much more cost effective then electric. I will take a SWAG and say 3/4' gas line is to big and a 3/4" is probably to small. For me the part the inspector wanted them to show was the pressure drops with everything on full blast to be sure everything was safe.

Comment: 3/4' - 3/4" are from the previous statements.